# DRY in CSS: repetitive queries

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, dry

I am learning (S)CSS and making my layout responsive by using container queries. Being used to factoring out repetitive code into functions, it hurts me that the code is so repetitive:

```scss
.sales-data-container {
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

@container learning-content (min-width: 45em) {
    .sales-data-container {
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}

@container learning-content (min-width: 54em) {
    .sales-data-container {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
}

@container learning-content (min-width: 70em) {
    .sales-data-container {
      font-size: 1.6em;
    }
}

@container learning-content (min-width: 90em) {
    .sales-data-container {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
}

// Potentially many more queries to handle various minimal widths in the same manner
```

All I am really doing here is repeating the same query for each of the pairs `[[45em, 0.8em], [54em, 1em], [70em, 1.6em], [90em, 2em]]`. Is there a way to write this shortly and nicely?

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/01/modern-fluid-typography-css-clamp/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interesting article, but does not seem to be related to what I am asking. If I am missing it, could you please point to a specific place where it is relevant?

Comment: you are trying to implement something called "fluid typography". I gave you the article that show how you should correctly do it. It's not related to your question.

Comment: Good ressource @TemaniAfif! If you're just looking to keep your output but to reduce the code, you could write a map and loop through it.